# Return https get request body value from async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, async-await, request

I'm trying to get the body.totalPages value so I can use it in another function block.  It successfully console.logs it however the returned value is undefined when I try using it in the getTotalGoals function.

```
function delay() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(42); 
        }, 3000);
    });
}

async function getPages(endpoint, teamParam) {
    var body = ''
    var results = await https.get((endpoint+teamParam), res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on("data", data => {
            body += data;
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            return body;
        });
    });
    await delay();
    console.log(body.totalPages);
    return body.totalPages;
}

async function getTotalGoals(team, year) {
    // endpoint config
    let endpoint = `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=${year}`;
    let homeParams = `&team1=${team}`;
    let awayParams = `&team2=${team}`;
    let homePages = 0;
    let awayPages = 0;
    let totalWins = 0;
    
    
    homePages = await getPages(endpoint, homeParams); // undefined here
    awayPages = await getPages(endpoint, awayParams);
    
    totalWins += await getWins(endpoint+homeParams, homePages);
    totalWins += await getWins(endpoint+awayParams, awayPages);
    
    console.log(totalWins);
}
```

Comment: If you're passing a callback function to `https.get`, then it's likely _not_ a promise, which it is required to be if you want to use async/await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `https.get` function with a promise and return the value with the `resolve()` function or return the error with the `reject()` function.

Example:

```
function getPages(endpoint, teamParam) {
    var body = ''

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        https.get((endpoint+teamParam), res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on("data", data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(body.totalPages)
            });
            res.on("error", (e) => {
                reject(e);
            });
        });
    });
    
}
```

Usage:

```
homePages = await getPages(endpoint, homeParams); // undefined here
```

Full code:

```
function delay() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(42); 
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function getPages(endpoint, teamParam) {
    var body = ''

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        https.get((endpoint+teamParam), res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on("data", data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(body.totalPages)
            });
            res.on("error", (e) => {
                reject(e);
            });
        });
    });
    
}

async function getTotalGoals(team, year) {
    // endpoint config
    let endpoint = `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=${year}`;
    let homeParams = `&team1=${team}`;
    let awayParams = `&team2=${team}`;
    let homePages = 0;
    let awayPages = 0;
    let totalWins = 0;
    
    
    homePages = await getPages(endpoint, homeParams); // undefined here
    awayPages = await getPages(endpoint, awayParams);
    
    totalWins += await getWins(endpoint+homeParams, homePages);
    totalWins += await getWins(endpoint+awayParams, awayPages);
    
    console.log(totalWins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback for `res.on('data', () => {})` is not a promise. Try this instead:

```js
async function getPages(endpoint, teamParam) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let body = '';
        https.get((endpoint+teamParam), res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on("data", data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(body.totalPages);
            });
        });
    });
}
```